# Image doesn't render properly / in full color

Tags: rendering, color

I'm just learning Blender so I am not sure if this is a common issue but while I attempted to render this image of a donut I made, a portion of the donut doesn't render with color and it appears to be showing a part of the donut which isn't there.

I've attached a screenshot of how the scene looks in the viewport and the other photo is that of the render.

[image]

[image: Rendered Image]

Not sure what the issue is here... The body of the donut is its own torus object.

Comment: Is there another object that is disabled for the viewport but enabled for rendering? https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7mzB.gif

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a second collection that is hidden but not disabled (box is still checked in the outliner). I'm guessing this collection contains a second donut. Even though it is hidden, it will still show up in the render. To make it not show in the render, you need to disable the collection by un-checking the box:

[image: Box]